# QGIS Modeler Raster Calculator

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler

My current goal is to calculate the following 
**(a<10)*a and (b<0.7)*b and c=2 and d=2**
this formula already worked in the native raster-calculator and now i'm trying to get this to work within the modeler. Long story short i can't get it to work.

---

got it to work with **((a<10)*a+(b<0.7)*b+(c=2)+(d=2))** but it's not the result i was hoping for, with the native calculator i get a new raster where one Attribute is NULL and the other one has a value which represents the area i'm looking for and now i get too much information...

is there anyway to include logical operators like 'and' to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Andreas! Maybe you can try the following (_untested_) in the **SAGA Raster Calculator**: `((a<10)*a)+((b<0.7)*b)+(c=2)+(d=2)`

Comment: @Joseph it seems like saga-rastercalculator doesn't really like the input. i get the error **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs'** and the log of my modul says in the saga part formula: (A=2)+((B

Comment: Hmm what QGIS version and platform (Windows, Linux etc) are you using? It runs for me without any errors (I use Windows 7 64-bit with QGIS 2.16.1).

Comment: Qgis 2.16.2 on windows 10 64 bit . I updated the original question with the results  i got,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some trial and error, going with the saga **reclass(simple)** in combination with the saga **rastercalculator** and the formula **g1+g2** worked like a charm, the main problem was that i was unable to use logic operators but this workaround worked just fine.